# Contour levels corresponding to variable levels in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, contour

I am trying to draw contour plot with ggplot2 and it is proving to be a little harder than I imagined. Using the `iris` dataset I am able to produce this plot:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x=Petal.Width, y=Petal.Length, fill=Sepal.Width)) +
  stat_density2d(geom="polygon", aes(fill=..level..))
```

[image]

My issue is that I can't seem to figure out how to display- rather than the density values -the raw `Sepal.Width` values. Here is what I've tried:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x=Petal.Width, y=Petal.Length, z=Sepal.Width)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill=Sepal.Width))+
  stat_contour(aes(colour=..level..))
```

This produces an especially odd error message:

```
 Warning message:
 Computation failed in `stat_contour()`:
 (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

I also tried this:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x=Petal.Width, y=Petal.Length, fill=Sepal.Width)) +
  stat_density2d(geom="polygon", aes(fill=Sepal.Width))
```

And lastly this:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x=Petal.Width, y=Petal.Length, fill=Sepal.Width)) +
  geom_tile()
```

Can anyone recommend a good way to produce a contour plot in ggplot2 with the values of the variable itself producing the levels of the contour?

**UPDATED**

From the `stat_contour` example:

```
# Generate data
library(reshape2) # for melt
volcano3d <- melt(volcano)
names(volcano3d) <- c("x", "y", "z")

# Basic plot
ggplot(volcano3d, aes(x, y, z = z)) +
 stat_contour(geom="polygon", aes(fill=..level..))
```

Work great and looks great. But if I apply this exactly to the iris example like so:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x=Petal.Width, y=Petal.Length, fill=Sepal.Width)) +
  stat_contour(geom="polygon", aes(fill=..level..))
```

I get this error message:

```
Warning message:
Computation failed in `stat_contour()`:
(list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

These are both dataframes with similar structure so I can't figure out what is different between the two causing this issue.

Comment: `stat_countour` needs a rectangular grid of values (like in the volcano3d example). if you have irregular data, you will need to choose a model to do some form of interpolation to calculate values for the grid you wish to plot. The `z` value you are seeing for `stat_density2d` really isn't doing anything. A density just predicts the joint density (~freqency) of those pairs of observations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ultimate solution to this way to use the `akima` package for interpolation then the `ggplot2` for final plotting. This is the method I used:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(akima)
library(dplyr)

interpdf <-interp2xyz(interp(x=iris$Petal.Width, y=iris$Petal.Length, z=iris$Sepal.Width, duplicate="mean"), data.frame=TRUE)

interpdf %>%
  filter(!is.na(z)) %>%
  tbl_df() %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y, z = z, fill = z)) + 
  geom_tile() + 
  geom_contour(color = "white", alpha = 0.05) + 
  scale_fill_distiller(palette="Spectral", na.value="white") + 
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try factorizing the `fill` in `stat_density2d()`

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x=Petal.Width, y=Petal.Length, fill=Sepal.Width)) +
    stat_density2d(geom="polygon", aes(fill = factor(..level..)))
```

[image]

Comment: This still produces the factor levels as densities rather than the actual values of `Sepal.Width`. Can you recommend how to set the contour levels by the `Sepal.Width` values?

Comment: I have the same problem.  Basically, I want / need to be able to plot 2 independent variables, then use **contour lines** for the dependent variable.  It surprises me that this is not easier to pull off, since ggplot2 is (rightfully) so strongly against 3-D perspective plots.

Comment: This produces contour densities, not raw contours based on a third variable. I too am trying to plot contours but my application is surveying data (axes are y = latitude, x = longitude) with the contour variable being elevation.